# Tiles with Leaflet from Qgis

Tags: qgis, leaflet, tiles, mbtiles

I tried QTILES plugin for QGIS and it works very well.
I can export tiles in .mbtiles or zip format.
Now I'm trying to know how call these tiles from leaflet in this way:

```
L.tileLayer('http://www.cityplanner.it/experiment_host/supply/tiles/car_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '..'
}).addTo(map);
```

(http://www.cityplanner.it/tilemill-alla-mappa-online/)

I don't know if is ok .mbtiles format or folder structure from .zip.

How leaflet reads .mbtiles?

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet does not natively get tiles out of an .mbtiles file. I think you should use an intermediate server for this. Have a look at this page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MBTiles

If your zip file has a folder structure similar to "zoom/x/y.png (or jpg or whatever image format)", then this is definitely the easiest to use: simply unzip on your drive or server, and it should work as soon as you specify the correct URL template to your Tile Layer.

Answer (score -2):

it works, here a first guide
webgis
leaflet
raster tiles
folder webgis - leaflet - project- data - raster/vector
1 raster georeferencing tif jpg
2 projectqgis save in /project/project.qgs
3 import raster in qgis
4 raster in folder /project/data/raster/raster1/raster.tif
5 better reprojection raster in
- wgs84z33 - 32633
- wgs84z32 - 32632
- or other wgs84zone
...continue here:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/639047012884139/permalink/818141158308056/?comment_id=818720828250089&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D